# SQL Summing and Grouping

Tags: sql, sum

How can I modify this query to display what it already does but also include the total SUM either in a separate row or column of InvPayAmnt per each select which has a unique CardName?

```
SELECT IdEntry, 
       DocNum, 
       'MICHIGAN' + CardCode, 
       QUOTENAME(CardName,'"'), 
       Convert(Decimal(10,2),InvPayAmnt), 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), T5.PmntDate,101), 
       NumAtCard, 
       PymMeth, 
       'Objtype' = CASE WHEN Objtype = 19 THEN 'CREDIT' ELSE 'INVOICE' END
FROM MICHIGAN.dbo.PWZ3
INNER JOIN MICHIGAN.dbo.OPWZ T5 ON T5.IdNumber = IdEntry
WHERE T5.PmntDate = '4/1/2011' 
AND T5.Canceled = 'N' 
AND Checked = 'Y'
UNION
SELECT IdEntry, 
       DocNum, 
       'BEN' + CardCode, 
       QUOTENAME(CardName,'"'), 
       Convert(Decimal(10,2),InvPayAmnt), 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),T5.PmntDate,101), 
       NumAtCard, 
       PymMeth, 
       'Objtype' = CASE WHEN Objtype = 19 THEN 'CREDIT' ELSE 'INVOICE' END
FROM BENSALEM.dbo.PWZ3
INNER JOIN BENSALEM.dbo.OPWZ T5 ON T5.IdNumber = IdEntry
WHERE T5.PmntDate = '4/1/2011' 
AND T5.Canceled = 'N' 
AND Checked = 'Y'
ORDER By 3

----------------CURRENT OUTPUT -----------------------------------
791 1608424 BENV5649        "K&C VENDOR"    1235.01 04/01/2011  10-111  EFT-JP      INVOICE
791 1608425 BENV5649        "K&C VENDOR"    215.00  04/01/2011  5801    EFT-JP  INVOICE
148 600913  MICHIGANV0077   "Tendercare"    18.03   04/01/2011  10/29   PM2 INVOICE
148 600916  MICHIGANV0077   "Tendercare"    48.08   04/01/2011  10/9    PM2 INVOICE

----------------REQUIRED OUTPUT-----------------------------------
791 1608424 BENV5649        "K&C VENDOR"    1450.01 04/01/2011  10-111  EFT-JP      SUM 
791 1608424 BENV5649        "K&C VENDOR"    1235.01 04/01/2011  10-111  EFT-JP      INVOICE  
791 1608425 BENV5649        "K&C VENDOR"    215.00  04/01/2011  5801    EFT-JP  INVOICE
148 600913  MICHIGANV0077   "Tendercare"    66.11   04/01/2011  10/29   PM2 SUM    
148 600913  MICHIGANV0077   "Tendercare"    18.03   04/01/2011  10/29   PM2 INVOICE
148 600916  MICHIGANV0077   "Tendercare"    48.08   04/01/2011  10/9    PM2 INVOICE
```

It would also work if the sum was placed in the last column, either way would be fine.

Comment: Can you show a small example of current output vs required output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the `convert()` call I assume you are using SQL Server.

If you have a fairly recent version (2005 or later), the following should work:

```
SELECT ....
       sum(InvPayAmnt) over (partition by CardName) as payment_sum
FROM ....
```